# ASP.NET MVC Assign value to hidden input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, input, hidden

I am currently in the process of creating an MVC application. I am trying to set it so that when an item is created, there are 4 properties gathered,
DocumentID, Name, Title and CreationDate. Only two of these properties should be alterable by the user, DocumentID is automatically hidden when I created the controlled. I have hidden CreationDate from the view but I am unsure of what should be my next step.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If an item is being created, then `DocumentID` and `CreationDate` should not even exist in the view - both properties should only be set when the object is saved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach would be to create view models containing only the values you need to edit. Submit the view model instead of the full entity, map the modified values onto the real entity, then persist the changes.

Comment: Whilst this may answer the question, I need a little help with the implementation. I have found this link, http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3 Is this the sort of thing that I should be implementing or am I miles off course?

Comment: It is something I struggled with a long time too. If you create a new sample MVC project take a look at the AccountController and Login/Registration models. They don't post User objects back to the controller, they post Login and Registration models that aren't linked to the database. On postback the values from those models are then assigned to a User object and passed to the UserManager to persist the changes.